# How to display license information in current language using doclicense package?

Tags: babel, languages, licensing, doclicense

I'm working in a template and I want to use the `doclicense` package and I want it to display license information accordingly to the current language. Unfortunately, for some reason, it is not doing as expected.

The minimal class file example `testclass.cls` is displayed below:

```
\ProvidesClass{testclass}
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage[brazilian,english]{babel}
\RequirePackage[
    type={CC},
    modifier={by},
    version={4.0},
]{doclicense}

\def\@keytest{
    \iflanguage{english}{test}{
    \iflanguage{portuguese}{TESTE}{not found}
    }}

\newcommand{\showtest}{%
 \@keytest\par 
 \doclicenseText\par
 \doclicenseIcon
}
```

and the `.tex` file is below:

```
\documentclass[brazilian,english]{testclass}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Teste}
\author{Eu}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{brazilian}
\maketitle

\showtest
\end{document}
```

The result achieved from the above code setting the language to `english` is:

[image: result using english]

and the result setting the language to `brazilian` is:

[image: result using brazilian]

Note that the article's date and the test variable (`keytest`) changed their values accordingly, but the license text did not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

doclicense hasn't code to change the language in the document. It will use whatever `\languagename` is set when the package is loaded.

If you want brazilian you could load the language definitions manually. Be aware that they contain empty lines  and spaces, so do it between paragraphs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[brazilian,english]{babel}
\RequirePackage[
    type={CC},
    modifier={by},
    version={4.0},
]{doclicense}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{brazilian}
\doclicenseText\par
\doclicenseIcon


\makeatletter\input{doclicense-brazilian.ldf}\makeatother
\doclicenseText\par
\doclicenseIcon
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the tip provided by [@ulrike-fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer), I've embedded the solution in a `newcommand`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[brazilian,english]{babel}
\RequirePackage[
    type={CC},
    modifier={by},
    version={4.0},
]{doclicense}

\newcommand{\tlprintlicense}{
    \iflanguage{english}{\makeatletter\input{doclicense-english.ldf}\makeatother\doclicenseText\par\doclicenseIcon}{
    \iflanguage{french}{\makeatletter\input{doclicense-french.ldf}\makeatother\doclicenseText\par\doclicenseIcon}{
    \iflanguage{german}{\makeatletter\input{doclicense-german.ldf}\makeatother\doclicenseText\par\doclicenseIcon}{
    \iflanguage{portuguese}{\makeatletter\input{doclicense-brazilian.ldf}\makeatother\doclicenseText\par\doclicenseIcon}{\doclicenseText\par\doclicenseIcon}
    }}}}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{brazilian}
\tlprintlicense

\selectlanguage{english}
\tlprintlicense
\end{document}
```